# proper way to send ajax json to play framework

Tags: ajax, json, scala, playframework-2.0

I've read a couple of posts here regarding how to do this and I can get it working only half-way.

This works (sending json object as text):

```
            function go(itemid)
            {
                apiRoutes.controllers.Application.addItem(itemid).ajax({
                    data:  '{"reqid":0,"iid":2,"description":"adsf"}',
                    dataType:  'text',
            contentType:'application/json',
                    success: function(reply) {
                        alert(reply)
                    }
                });
            }
```

This does not (sending object as json):

```
            function go(itemid)
            {
                apiRoutes.controllers.Application.addItem(itemid).ajax({
                    data:  {"reqid":0,"iid":2,"description":"adsf"},
                    dataType:  'text',
            contentType:'application/json',
                    success: function(reply) {
                        alert(reply)
                    }
                });
            }
```

And what I really want to do is something like this (I've already set up the proper combinators):

```
            function go(itemid)
            {
                apiRoutes.controllers.Application.addItem(itemid).ajax({
                    data:  @Html(Json.stringify(Json.toJson(item))),
                    dataType:  'text',
            contentType:'application/json',
                    success: function(reply) {
                        alert(reply)
                    }
                });
            }
```

My controller looks like this:

```
  def addItem(id: Long) = Action (parse.json) { implicit request =>
    Logger.info("add item")
    request.body.validate(Item.itemReads).map { item =>
    thing.addItem(item)
    Ok("Succesfully added item.")
    }.recoverTotal{
      e => BadRequest("Detected error:"+ JsError.toFlatJson(e))
    }
  }
```

In the second case, it never gets to the logging code.  Instead it returns a 400 Bad Request immediately (this is likely something triggered in the Action (parse.json) bit I think).

I'd rather send the object as json because when I convert to string and description happens to have an apostrophe in it (') that messes things up.  I could probaby escape the apostrophe, but hoping that I'm missing something simple about how to do this with an object rather than a string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) the `dataType` param is for setting:

> The type of data that you're **expecting back from the server**.

For sending the json use your second approach (don't send it as a String). Use web browser inspector to validate if correct data were send. AFAIK you shouldn't have problem with [Handling the JSON request](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaJsonRequests) after receiving valid JSON object

Comment: I made some edits to the question.  I understand now that the dataType has to do with the response, but I'm still having an issue sending the JSON object back.  It looks to me like valid JSON but I keep getting an "Invalid JSON" 400 error.  This is not thrown by my controller code directly as it never manages to get to the Logging statement.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. The answer is checked, but I don't see anything different. Are you still having to stringify the json object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send a non-stringified JSON object in Jquery, $.ajax automatically tries to process it with $.param,

If your data in the ajax call looks like this:

```
data:  {"reqid":0,"iid":2,"description":"adsf"}
```

This is what $.ajax is doing under the hood before sending:

```
$.param({"reqid":0,"iid":2,"description":"adsf"})
// "reqid=0&iid=2&description=adsf"
```

It takes the JSON and serializes it into a form-url-encoded format. Whereas your server is expecting JSON. I would suggest the best way to get around this is to just stringify before sending:

```
data:  JSON.stringify({"reqid":0,"iid":2,"description":"adsf"})
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#sending-data-to-server